# How to design models with Firestore?

Tags: javascript, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Cloud Firestore. After reading the docs, what is still unclear to me is:

Is Firestore local caching etc. so good that I can replace my local variables with it?

Meaning that when I design my models I do not need to cache data in variables but can directly access the firebase db?

```
getSettings() {
  return db.collection('Settings').get(settingsId);
}
```

Edit: I use Firestore for Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android and iOS the [offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) is enabled by default, while for web environment is not. You need to enable it in order to be able to use it.

When you activate this feature, it means that a local copy of the database is created on user's device. And yes, if you have a collection of `Settings`, you can get the data directly from chached data. For that you can make a get call to get the corresponding settings/documents that you need.

Comment: I use it for web. And there the manual says: "For the web, offline persistence is an experimental feature"

Comment: That's correct but you can still use it, right? I think that in the future will become a nonexperimental feature.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My bad, sorry about that. Just updated my answer. Thanks again for correcting me.